# What is the function used to lookup the specific criteria in one column, and bring in the second column (next to it)? See example below

Tags: excel

I tried using a VLOOKUP here using the following (B$1 is not shown below in Sheet1, but would have the criteria I'm looking to bring in ("AN")):

```
=VLOOKUP(B$1,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here?

**Sheet1:**

```
Column A 
--------------------------------------------------------------------| 
Name                                                                | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------|
Use Function to Insert from Column B, Sheet 2 based on criteria "AN"|
should come back as "1.1 Name1"                                     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------|   
Use Function to Insert from Column B, Sheet 2 based on criteria "AN"| 
should come back as "1.3 Name3"                                     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------|
And so on...
```

**Sheet2:**

```
Column A|Column B | 
--------|---------|
AN      |1.1 Name1|
--------|---------|
W       |1.2 Name2|
--------|---------|
AN      |1.3 Name3|
--------|---------|
```

Comment: @pnuts - That's what I did. I put the example criteria I want "AN" into that cell, it's just hidden in the example I have given above.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in A1 on Sheet1 and copy down till you get blanks:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Sheet2!$B$1:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!A:A)))/(Sheet2!$B$1:INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH("zzz",Sheet2!A:A))=$B$1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have mentioned the formula in Sheet1!A1 as "=vlookup(B1,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)" and in sheet1!B1 you have "AN" so it should be resulting in the corresponding value from Sheet2 right next to AN (*"1.1 Name1"*)

Comment: It's only coming back as "1.1 Name1". I'm looking for "1.3 Name3", etc. (all values in Sheet 2, Column B that have an "AN" next to it in Column A).